# to show the text in the textarea when we are typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need solution for the following problem?

when i'am typing text in one textarea it should should write the same text in another text area dynamically and concurrently

Example:

text area1         text area2

Now when i'am typing or deleting text in area1 it should concurrently and dynamically do that same operation in text area2 and user should view both of them using jquery or js.

Comment: did you look up the [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup) event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use keyup

```
 $('#textarea1').keyup(function(){
        $('#textarea2').val(this.value);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#textArea1").change(function(){
    $("#textArea2").val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) function:-

```
$("#textarea1").keyup( function() {
$("#textarea2").val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

working example

html :

```
<textarea id='text1'></textarea>
<textarea id='text2'></textarea>
```

jquery :

```
$('#text1').keyup(function(e){
     $("#text2").val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Should be `.val`, not `.html`.

Comment: I have edit the answer with `val`